# Global access to view properties

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

A containerView1 with 3 buttons which will need their text changed and their visibility modified according to user interaction with views in  a different containerView2.
Each containerView has its viewController and there is the main viewController for the main storyBoard. The buttons will need to be Outlets as well as Actions.

Since the buttons are in a container whose controller is embedded segue, no prepareForSegue is allowed since there is no "segueing" here since the embed type is called during setup only.

What mechanise is best fit to be able to access the properties of the buttons from anywhere and how to implement it?

thanks

[image]

Comment: from *anywhere*? That probably is not a good idea - setup a delegation system where everybody delegates what he has to and becomes delegate of everything he has to. In general to get hold of the containerViewControllers you need to get hold of them in the prepareForSegue-method.

Comment: I would appreciate a swift example to see it working and understand it. :)

Comment: on your right you see the Related widget. The second link with 709 upvotes will tell you more. It will give you al the needed search terms, just add swift to them.